# How to request datas to server in post method ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, parsing, post

Hi I am new to ios post method.In my app i want to show list of values.
The request format is:

```
{"customerId":"000536","requestHeader":{"userId":"000536"}}
```

The code i used is:

```
NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
    NSString *post =[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"customerId=%@&userId=%@",@"000536",@"000536"];
    NSLog(@"PostData: %@",post);

    NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://servelet/URL"];
    NSDictionary *jsonDict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                              @"000536", @"customerId",
                              @"000536", @"userId",
                              nil];

    NSError *error;
    NSData *postData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:jsonDict options:0 error:&error];

    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[postData length]];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setURL:url];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json; character=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];

    //[NSURLRequest setAllowsAnyHTTPSCertificate:YES forHost:[url host]];
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:queue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response,NSData *data, NSError *error){
        // NSLog(@"Response code: %ld", (long)[response statusCode]);
        if(error || !data){
            NSLog(@"Server Error : %@", error);
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"Server Response :%@",response);
            NSError* error;
            NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization
                                  JSONObjectWithData:data
                                  options:kNilOptions
                                  error:&error];

            NSArray* latest = [json objectForKey:@"apptModel"];
            NSLog(@"items: %@", latest);
        }
    }
     ];
```

The response is : (null)

How to request the values with same format as shown above?Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ask your server why it returns an empty response.  Or check what the response is, and if it's valid JSON.

Comment: From your Request Format {"customerId":"000536","requestHeader":{"userId":"000536"}}
 I found that customerId and UserId both are having Same value.
So you need to ask server guy to update request for same.
And other thing you may need to pass userId as **Request Header** instaedof adding that in to request dictionary

Comment: response i am getting in post man as "{"responseHeader":{"responseCode":0,"responseMessage":"Success"},"apptModel":[{"customerid":"000536","perfomerid":"000004","Name":"Dr","LastName":"abc","Gender":"MALE","Specialization":"abc","Description":"abc"},""......@Avi @Bhavik

Comment: validate your response with json validator.
[JsonValidator](http://json.parser.online.fr/)

Comment: {
 "responseHeader": {
  "responseCode": 0,
  "responseMessage": "Success"
 },
 "apptModel": [{
  "customerid": "000536",
  "perfomerid": "000004",
  "FirstName": "Dr",
  "LastName": "abc",
  "Gender": "MALE",
  "Specialization": "abc",
  "Description": "abc"
 }]} @Bhavik

Comment: Are your sure your POST parameters are good, because `postData` and `post` doesn't looks like the JSON you gave at the beginning: `{"customerId":"000536","requestHeader":{"userId":"000536"}}`. It should be `NSDictionary *jsonDict =  @{@"customerId":@"000536",@"requestHeader":@{@"userId":@"000536"}};`

Comment: NSDictionary *jsonDict = @{@"customerId":@"000536",@"requestHeader":@{@"userId":@"000536"}}; gives me a response as: "items: {
    responseCode = 1;
    responseMessage = "Please enter all vital fields.";
}" @Larme

Comment: Could you show us screenshots of what you put exactly in POSTMAN when it works?

Answer (score 1):

Use This Code

```
NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
NSString *post =[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"customerId=%@&userId=%@",@"000536",@"000536"];
NSLog(@"PostData: %@",post);

NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://servelet/URL"];
NSDictionary *jsonDict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                          @"000536", @"customerId",
                          @"000536", @"userId",
                          nil];

NSError *error;
NSData *postData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:jsonDict options:0 error:&error];

NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[postData length]];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:url];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[request setValue:@"application/json; character=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];

//[NSURLRequest setAllowsAnyHTTPSCertificate:YES forHost:[url host]];
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *err)
{
    // NSLog(@"Response code: %ld", (long)[response statusCode]);
    if(error || !data){
        NSLog(@"Server Error : %@", error);
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Server Response :%@",response);
        NSError* error;
        NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization
                              JSONObjectWithData:data
                              options:kNilOptions
                              error:&error];

        NSArray* latest = [json objectForKey:@"apptModel"];
        NSLog(@"items: %@", latest);
    }
}];
[task resume];
```

Comment: what is the change @PinkeshGjr. I still gets (null) value.

Comment: debug and then check generated url is working in browser

Comment: Yes its working in browser --PinkeshGjr. Find above comments and responses i shown.

Comment: have you added App Transport Security in Info.plist?<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>

Comment: There might be something you missing @Vignesh